# iphone Three20 TTNavigator UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, three20, ttnavigator

Not sure if what I want to do makes sense, but I want to take advantage of the UITabBarController and the TTNavigator from Three20.  Any tutorials around that demonstrate how this can be done?  I understand how to add view controllers to the navigator using the TTURLMap, but do I need to add a navigator for each tabbar item?  I'm lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Three20 [TTNavigator Demo](http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTNavigatorDemo/). It shows you how to use Three20 with a UITabBarController.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Figures it was right in front of my face the whole time inside the three20 package.  Do you have any idea where I can find more info about using the TTMessageController with either the user's address book or a custom set of data that is returned from a query on my server?  Looks like the example in the Catalog app uses an array with names only.